На какую глубину можно просчитать в игре пентаго ходы?
Потихоньку пишу игру на питоне пока что просто игру а потом и решатель для нее. Еще ничего не написал пока что просто сделал картинки.
И еще ничего не написав задался вопросом на какую глубину можно будет просчитать ходы?



Не только лишь все знают, что это за игра. Хорошо бы какие-то ссылки дать на правила игры хотя бы.

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE

Глубина просчета ходов в игре Пентаго зависит от нескольких факторов, включая мощность компьютера, используемые алгоритмы и оптимизацию кода. В общем случае, для игр с высокой комбинаторной сложностью, таких как Пентаго, глубина просчета может быть ограничена.
Для Пентаго, как и для других стратегических игр, часто используются алгоритмы типа Минимакс с Альфа-Бета отсечением. Эти алгоритмы позволяют эффективно просчитывать ходы на несколько шагов вперед, уменьшая количество рассматриваемых вариантов.
На практике, глубина просчета может варьироваться от 5 до 10 ходов в зависимости от сложности позиции и доступных вычислительных ресурсов2. Более глубокий анализ требует значительно больше времени и ресурсов, поэтому часто используются эвристики и оценки для сокращения времени вычислений.
